# OnSelect handler with XUL and Javascript

Tags: javascript, tree, xul, onselect

So I have a tree of items created using XUL. When I select item from this tree and click a View button I want to display information about the selected item. I do it as below but the button does not work at all.

Assign an id for the tree:

```
<tree id="assetList" flex="1" multiple="false">
```

Then I attach a function to the button:

```
<button id="view-button" align="right" class="dialog" label="View" oncommand="view()" />
```

Then I have function view written as bellow:

```
function view(){    
  var tree = document.getElementById("assetList");
  var items = tree.selectedItems;
  if(items.length == 0)
    alert("No item was selected");
  else if(items.length > 1)
    alert("Please select one item at a time");
  else{
    txt = items.getAttribute('id'); //it's just for testing right now
    alert(txt);
  }
}
```

Even when I don't select anything and click view the alert message is not fired. What did I do wrong? and How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: so I add seltype="single" to the <tree> so users can select only 1 row at a time. I use tree.currentIndex to get the position where user selects. However, I couldn't find any function to retrieve the element at that position. Can someone give me some hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. I can use getItemAtIndex(tree.currentIndex).